# Cleanest way to make GLPK clean up at the program termination

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, glpk

I'm using GNU Linear Programming Kit at my program. Everything works fine, but when I checked program with valgrind I found some memory leaks:

```
==7051== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==7051==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==7051==    by 0x52CFACB: glp_init_env (in /usr/lib/libglpk.so.0.30.0)
==7051==    by 0x52CFC1C: ??? (in /usr/lib/libglpk.so.0.30.0)
==7051==    by 0x52D0211: glp_malloc (in /usr/lib/libglpk.so.0.30.0)
==7051==    by 0x52AC50A: glp_create_prob (in /usr/lib/libglpk.so.0.30.0)
```

According to documentation `glp_init_env(void)` is called on first use of any GLPK API call. But to clean it up, one would have need to call `glp_free_env(void)`.

I want my program to be memory leak free, and simply calling `glp_free_env();` manually isn't a good solution for me - I have some unit tests written with Boost Unit Test Framework and I want them to be memory leak free too.

Ideally I would use some C++ feature that could call it automatically on program termination. Do you know any simple and clean way do do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to call `free` functions to match your `init` functions?

Comment: I think the issue is that `..init..` is called automatically inside the library, not directly by user code.

Comment: Yes, I don't call the init directly. What is more I need to carefully choose when I actually dealt with library since simply running `glp_free_env()` after I used the library ended up with `SIGABRT` or similar. If I run function on a program termination there would be no risk of such event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [benjymous's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785443/321013) isn't appropriate for some reason or other, [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) may help:

```
int atexit( void (*func)() );
```

> Registers the function pointed to by func to be called on normal
>   program termination (via std::exit() or returning from the
>   cpp/language/main function)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
class CleanupOnExit
{
public:
    ~CleanupOnExit()
    {
        glp_free_env(void);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    CleanupOnExit cleanup;

    .. do any processing here ..

    return 0;
}
```

`cleanup`'s destructor will be called automatically at the end of `main` (even if you return in the middle, or throw an exception.)

Comment: A better approach would be to have that class do the init as well.

Comment: There's also Boost Unit Test Framework - it creates main() function automatically, so your approach solves only part of my problem.